# Error using as.H2o in R

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o

Getting error when using as.h2o. Anyone have ideas?

```
library(pacman)
p_load(h2o)
data(iris)
localH2O = h2o.init(ip = 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX', port = XXXXX, strict_version_check = FALSE)
train_hex <-  as.h2o(iris, destination_frame = "train_hex")
|=====================================================| 100%
Error in class(obj) <- "rs.scalar" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

If I try not to assign it, this is the error.

```
as.h2o(iris,  destination_frame = "train_hex")
|===================================================| 100%
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
 Error in if (ncol(x) > 1) " columns]" else " column]" : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here is some additional information about my environment and computing situation.

Version 0.99.896 – © 2009-2016 RStudio, Inc.

```
R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
H2O cluster uptime:         49 days 22 hours 
H2O cluster version:        3.9.1.99999 
H2O cluster name:           H2O_29276 
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   17.29 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    24 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  4 
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
H2O Connection ip:          
H2O Connection port:         
H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
R Version:                  R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] h2o_3.8.2.6    statmod_1.4.24 pacman_0.4.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3     RCurl_1.95-4.8  jsonlite_0.9.20
[4] bitops_1.0-6
```

Comment: Do you use `RStudio`? There the error was reported, but not in base **R**, see [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202339776--rs-scalar-error)

Comment: Can you show more code, or a full reproducible example? Or more about your environment? It works for me (from within RStudio, on Linux, 64-bit)

Comment: Sorry for the delay @DarrenCook. I have added my environment information. I just tried it again and it still does not work. Anyone from h2o lurking and can help?

Comment: @Scott No obvious problem there. What is the code you are using? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I also tried uninstalling, reinstalling package per [this](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/1247/docs-website/Ruser/R_studio.html). After install I got message `Error in fetch(key) : 
  lazy-load database '/home/Scott.Jacobs/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/h2o/help/h2o.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In fetch(key) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1`

Comment: Those are the version 2 install instructions. I've posted an answer, with a link to latest uninstall/install instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably due to running incompatible versions and/or running a development version (the ".9999" at the end of the version number) on your cluster.

I suggest you un-install, and install the latest R client, following [these instructions](http://www.h2o.ai/download/h2o/r).  Try latest stable-build, then if no luck, try the nightly build. And if still no luck, consider upgrading your cluster to either the latest stable, or latest nightly.